# I am trying the rewrite the URL, but getting internal server error 500

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rules

This is the URL:

```
https://example.com/demo-2/project-details?pid=9&slug=Ace-Starlit`
```

and I am trying to convert the above URL into this:

```
https://example.com/demo-2/project/9/ace-starlit
```

**demo-2** is a directory.

below is my `.htaccess` code -

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php \[L,QSA\]

RewriteRule ^demo-2/project/(.\*)/(.\*) /demo-2/project-details.php?pid=$1&slug=$2 \[QSA,L\]
```

Comment: From your directives, it looks like you are also using extensionless URLs for other requests - is that the case?

Comment: You've also backslash-escaped various characters in your rules, which makes this invalid (and would result in a 500 error, which may or may not be the cause of your actual problem). Use the formatting tools provided to format code blocks. Please correct this.

Comment: Yes, I have removed .php extension from the url

Answer (score 0):

You should change the order of the rules and make your regex more specific. eg. Match digits only in the 3rd path segment, not *anything* (`.*` is often used too much).

Have your rules like this instead in the root `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on

# Specific rewrite
RewriteRule ^demo-2/project/(\d+)/([^\]+)$ /demo-2/project-details.php?pid=$1&slug=$2 [QSA,L]

# Append ".php" to other URLs if they exist
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f 
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [L]
```

However, there is still an issue with this that is not easily resolvable in `.htaccess`. You have `ace-starlift` in the URL-path, but you would seem to be expecting `Ace-Starlift` in your URL parameter. You should resolve this in your PHP code if possible.

With regards to the rule that appends the `.php` extension... there is no need to check that the request does not map to a file or directory before checking that the request+".php" exists. The conditions are (or should be) mutually exclusive.